# Change clock frequency from 50MHz to 40MHz using Altera Cyclone IV and Quartus Lite 20.1

Tags: fpga, frequency, intel-fpga, quartus, cyclone

I'm using the FPGA board EasyFPGAv2.2 which have Altera Cyclone IV with chip EP4CE6E22C6 and I made a verilog program to generate VGA 640x480 60Hz signal. It works great dividing 50MHz by 2 generating 25MHz clock frequency. But now I want to go up and generate a VGA 800x600 signal and for this is necesary to have a 40MHz clock. I'm using Quartus Lite 20.1 and I dont know how to achieve this step. I'm newbie with FPGA and Quartus software. Thank you.

Comment: 0

I don't know enough of the details to write a good answer, but I can suggest a direction for you to research. I see that the FPGA you are using has 2 PLLs. Using a PLL could be a good way to generate a 40 MHz clock output based on a 50 MHz clock input.

Comment: You'd typically use a PLL to do this. The EP4Cx6E22 device has 2 multipurpose PLLs which would be suited. You'll also need to ensure that you watch the 'LOCK' bit (essentially a PLL valid/ready bit) to know that the desired frequency arrangement is met.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand what you suggest, But I dont know how to doit in Quartus :(

Answer (score 1):

Use a PLL. Divide your 50 MHz by 5 to get 10 MHz. Then configure the feedback divider in the PLL to divide by 4, and you'll get 40 MHz.